# "object container" and pointers

Tags: c++, object, pointers

First of all I would like to show some code, maybe  it will help.

```
CBank *Bank;

COkno Okno(Bank);
CBohater Bohater(Bank);
CKlawiatura Klawiatura(Bank);
CWszystkiePlatformy WszystkiePlatformy(Bank);
Bank = new CBank(&Okno, &Bohater, &Klawiatura, &WszystkiePlatformy);
```

The main idea is to place all of above classes with exception of CBank which will group them, and then let the grouped classes access to each other. I don't know if I'm doing it right way. When trying the code above the pointer in classes COkno ... etc is outdated and don't store right data.

Comment: You need to clarify the problem you are actually trying to solve and ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 3):

You're storing pointers to objects that have automatic storage duration (at least, you may be, hard to tell from the way your example is posted).  When they leave their current scope pointers to them become invalid.

Next, you pass `Bank`, a pointer to a `CBank` object to each of them, yet you do so before it is initialized.  A copy is made and, when `Bank` is later initialized, it is set to a new value, but your other objects still have a copy of an invalid pointer hanging around.  Bad idea.

You have a strange dependency here.  You need a `CBank` pointer to pass to these three constructors, but at the same time you need those three objects to pass to the `CBank` constructor.  The dependency is circular and this is a poor design.

What you can do is change `CBank` to construct these objects internally.  If there is no need for dynamic memory allocation... well, don't use it.  If it is required then `new` up the objects inside `CBank` or in `CBank`'s constructor and deallocate them in the destructor (don't forget to adhere to the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) if you do this!).

Ask yourself; are these dependencies *really* necessary?  Can you simplify this relationship?

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version would be to have 2 objects that try to refer to each other:

```
class A {
    A(A* other);
};

A* one = new A(two); // ?
A* two = new A(one);
```

(Here there's one class, you have different classes-  this doesn't matter really).

This obviously doesn't work because `one` can't refer to `two` before `two` is created.

I'm afraid there's no reasonable way to do this other than two-phase initialization. The objects need to be created in *some* way and one of them needs to acknowledge that the second one doesn't yet exist.

Hence something like:

```
class A {
    A(A* other);
    A();
    // ...
};

A* one = new A();
B* two = new A(one);
one->setOtherReference(two);
```

Yes, this implies two-phase initialization, i.e. there's a time when `one` is created but not yet fully initialized (waiting for `setOtherReference()` which it requires to function).

*BTW: Chances are you can just simplify your design to avoid this!*